# ¿Cómo puedo definir o que tipo de variable puedo realzar para el siguiente problema?

Tags: flutter, dart

que operador podría utilizar para definir 2.5 km = $ 35 si pasa de 2.5 km aumenta cada 1 km $ 10, pero si esta dentro de los 2.5 sigue siendo = $ 35

```html
  void calculatePrice() async {
    Prices prices = await _pricesProvider.getAll();
    double kmValue = double.parse(km.split(" ")[0]) * prices.km;// vamos a multiplicar los km que vienen en el valor por los km que tengo en la base de datos que ahorita son 1.5 cada km
    double minValue = double.parse(min.split(" ")[0]) * prices.min; // vamos a multiplicar los min que vienen en el valor por los min que tengo en la base de datos que ahorita son 0.5 cada min
    double total = kmValue + minValue;


    minTotal = total  + 10;
    maxTotal = total + 35;

    refresh();
  }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: @Comunidad listo agregue mi código

Comment: No entiendo. Tienes un `km` al que le haces split y lo usas para calcular cosas. Por qué no validas si es mayor o menor a 2.5?

Comment: @Alfabravo "km" me refiero a kilometros. en este caso lo que quiero es que cuando un servicio abarque de 0 a 2.5 kilometros sea una tarifa igual a $35. si se pasa de los 2.5 kilometros cada kilometro se cobrara a $10 entonces al finalizar debo sumar los $35 mas los kilometros recorridos

Comment: A ver me explico. En **tu código** tienes `km.split(" ")[0]` y eso lo multiplicas por un precio, al parecer. Eso no es lo que necesitas validar que sea menor a 2.5?????

Comment: @Alfabravo exacto eso lo multiplico para dar un precio, entonces lo que necesito ahora es hacer una condición que cuando sean menos de 2.5 km se cobre mi tarifa mínima los $35 si se pasan de los 2.5 km debo cobrar la tarifa mínima mas los KM recorridos que cada KM se cobra $10

Comment: Pues haz exactamente eso. Réstale 2.5 al valor de kilómetros y si el resultado es positivo, multiplicas el resultado por 10 y se lo sumas a la tarifa mínima, no?????????????

Comment: @Alfabravo perdón  estoy empezando en dart y no se como podría hacer eso en código